# Gunicorn Flask application in Docker Container not getting Exposed

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes, gunicorn

The application inside the container is inaccessible from the outside i.e if I exec into the docker container and do

```sh
curl localhost:5000
```

it works correctly but not on the browser in my computer i get error : This site cant be reached

My Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /web-engine

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /web-engine

# Install Gunicorn3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc -y

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

# Define environment variable
ENV username root

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD gunicorn --workers 4 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 application:app --threads 1
```

UPON executing docker in this way:

```sh
sudo docker run -e password=$password -p 5000:5000 $reg/web-engine:ve0.0.2
```

I get the following output:

```
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (6)
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2019-09-08 11:53:36 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

So as you can see I'm mapping port 5000 of the container to port 5000 of my computer but localhost:5000 is not working

Therefore i tried everthing the same but with the development server of Flask
with the following change in My dockerfile

FRom

```sh
CMD gunicorn --workers 4 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 application:app --threads 1
```

TO

```sh
CMD python3.7 application.py
```

and IT WORKED; I goto localhost:5000 and see the application is working

There is nothing wrong with the application. I suppose there's an error in gunicorn server

the requirements.txt file :

```
Flask
Flask-SQLAlchemy
mysqlclient
gunicorn
bs4
html5lib
```

Please help me out

I also tried different forms of gunicorn and docker run command combinations like

```sh
CMD gunicorn -application:app && sudo docker run -e password=$password -p 5000:8000 $reg/web-engine:ve0.0.2
```

It didnt work
[terminal image of container working with development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ors.png)

I would appreciate a solution involving nothing outside whats mentioned here like nginx, supervisor etc
 SOmeone please helllppp meeeeee.......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, 127.0.0.1 means a different thing inside the container than it does outside. Use `0.0.0.0:5000` instead.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the other answer: the way Docker port forwarding works is to forward from the IPs on the host machine to *one* address in the container. Specifically, the external address that talks to the Docker bridge network that connects the container to the host network. It can't talk to to `127.0.0.1` on the container because that's a private IP—the host has its own `127.0.0.1`.

So you need to either bind to that Docker bridge network, or just bind to all interfaces by binding to `0.0.0.0`, which is the easiest solution.

Explaining this with prose is a little tricky, but I have longer version that also includes diagrams and will probably therefore be easier to understand: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Answer (score -2):

Try this command in your Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Hi Kennedy, thanks for answering. However, your answer is not adding any further information than the existing answers already provide.